# How to write replace function more elegant?

Tags: ruby, regex, optimization, replace, gsub

I wrote some function which replace one value in a string. 
It take me some time to figure-out it basing on varius docs, but I would like to ask some champions in RUBY about RIGHT WAY, how to code this?

```
def replace(newValue)
=begin
    [0]: A0000001561234 = 10,10,1,X,0,0,12345,12345
    1.  A0000001561234 =
    2.  10
    3.  10
    4.  1
    5.  X
    6.  0
    7.  0
    8.  12345
    9.  12345
    //source - http://rubular.com/
=end
    Dir.foreach('./') do |item|
        next if item == '.' or item == '..'
        if item =~ /(.*)online(.*)/
            IO.write(item, File.open(item) do |f| f.read.gsub(/^(A000[0-9]{10}.*)([0-9]{2})\,(.*)\,(.*)\,(.*)\,(.*)\,(.*)\,([1-5]*)\,([1-5]*)\n/x, "\\1\\2,\\3,\\4,\\5,\\6,\\7,#{newValue},\\9\n" ) end)
            puts "done"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: As a stylistic thing, and to write idiomatic Ruby, don't use block comments with `=begin`/`=end` inside your method as if Ruby was Python. Instead, move that immediately ahead of your method, and use the standard `#` comment marks. RDoc will be able to find, and incorporate that information into documentation for your code automatically. Also use two spaces for indenting, not four.

Comment: You should show an example of your expected output. The Rubular extract helps a little for seeing what you're parsing, but that shows how you're doing it, not necessarily how it *should* be done, and it does nothing to show us what your expected output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just readable variant:

```
f.read.gsub( /^(A000[0-9]{10})\s*=\s*(.*)/ ) do | _ |
    values = $2.split( ',' )
    values[ 6 ] = new_value
    "A000#{$1} = #{values.join( ',' )}"
end
```

`_` means, that the argument is passed, but isn't used in a fucntion or block, please refer to the [good code standart](http://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#syntax). `_` shell be used, when the block strongly requires the explicitly declared argument, and other way, for example, in the code above, it is not needed, and could be just omitted. Also for *ruby* above equal *1.9* you can use the named group argument for a `Regexp`, so the code could be optimized as follows:

```
f.read.gsub( /^(?<key>A000[0-9]{10})\s*=\s*(?<valueset>.*)/ ) do
    values = valueset.split( ',' )
    values[ 6 ] = new_value
    "A000#{key} = #{values.join( ',' )}"
end
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of `do | _ |` ? I mean, why `| _ |` and not an assignment to a readable variable name?

Comment: @pduersteler `_` means than the argument is passed, but isn't used in a fucntion, or block, please see here: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#syntax

Comment: `_` this mean unused variable. Why do you need a variable in the block if you do not use it?

Comment: @Monk_Code Some times it is required, in the code above it is not needed. I did't intend to omit it, to show the availability, and increase readability of the code

Comment: if you do not need, you can not write.

Comment: @Monk_Code I've explained the reason.

Comment: Do not use `$2`. Instead of that use `(?<varname>.*)`.

Comment: according to present solution 

`"A000#{$1} = #{values.join( ',' )}"`
this will and overmuch string A000. Without this works fine and looks perfectly :) Thank you @majioa.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier for which ruby that rule is valid? for ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: @Artur_PL without `A000` it looks perfectly, ok, I don't know yuor needs, you may change the match rule as you wish.

Comment: @majioa - for 1.9 up. It is also in [bbatsov's Style Guide which you linked](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#regular-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're following a very round-about path to replace the 8th capture in your pattern. Instead, do it directly, without messing around with an overly complex regular expression:

```
new_value = 'foobar'
str = 'A0000001561234 = 10,10,1,X,0,0,12345,12345'

values = str.split(',') # => ["A0000001561234 = 10", "10", "1", "X", "0", "0", "12345", "12345"]
values[-2] = new_value
values.join(',') # => "A0000001561234 = 10,10,1,X,0,0,foobar,12345"
```

`values[-2] = new_value` is a quick way to index from the end of an array and assign to that slot. Then the code only needs to reassemble the comma-delimited string.

Comment: the issues is that this is part of text file, and replaced could be also string between '=' and ','. But thank you for presenting also other way, I maybe use it in other part of code. :)